# activity diagram - how to show multiple objects passed between two actions?

Tags: uml

### Background

I have one action (**action_a**) that calls an operation(**operation_x**) on another action (**action_b**).

The parameters to **operation_x** are as follows:

```
action_b.operation_x( param_1, param_2 )
```

I'm trying to work out how to document the parameters being passed in UML activity diagrams.

### Option 1

One option may be to use a comment?

[image: Diagram]

### Option 2

Another option may be to use activity parameters, but it doesn't seem right to show two flows from action_a for one operation call?

[image]

### Question

How can I show multiple objects being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is close, but the edges coming out of `action_a` are not right, and I don't think it's legal to show the call and the details on the same diagram. Please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130552/2596664).