# activity diagram - call operation example with parameters?

Tags: uml

I'm looking for an example of an activity diagram where one action is a Call Operation Action and is calling another action with more than one parameter being passed.

I have search quite a few uml books, search online and gone through the uml2 specification but cannot find an example representing the above.

This question is similar to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090848/activity-diagram-how-to-show-multiple-objects-passed-between-two-actions), but is much more specific hence I don't think it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the rights to post examples of my own work, but you can see Conrad Bock's excellent series of articles. In section 4 of [column 4](http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2003_09/column4/) of the series, he has examples of exactly what you're looking for. I don't have the fUML spec handy, but I remember seeing many unit tests that taught me a lot about activity diagram token semantics. Those were eye opening! I can't remember whether these tests were in the spec or in Ed Seidewitz's open-source fUML implementation.

Comment: Jim - is this the fUML implementation you are talking about: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.modeldriven/fuml/1.1.0/

Comment: That looks like a snapshot of it.